# php: getting a variable (user selection from radio button) to another file

Tags: php, radio-button

I have a list of items in one file (fruit.php):

```
<form action="delete_items.php" method="post">
     <input type="radio" value="apple" name="fruit">Apple<br>
     <input type="radio" value="pear" name="fruit">Pear<br>
     <input type="radio" value="banana" name="fruit">Banana<br>
     <input type="submit" value="delete" name="deleteButton"><br>
</form>
```

In the delete_items.php, I have a variable that stores the selection:

```
<?php
    $selection = $_POST["fruit"];

    echo "are you sure you want to delete it?";
    echo '<form action="delete_confirmation.php" method="post"><br>';
    echo '<input type="submit" name="deleteYes" value="Yes"><br>';
    echo '<input type="submit" name="deleteNo" value="No"><br>';
    echo '</form>';
?>
```

Than in the confirmation file (delete_confirmation.php):

```
<?php
      include 'delete_items.php';
                     
      if($_POST["deleteYes"]){
           $query = 'DELETE FROM databaseName WHERE fruitName="' . $selection . '"';
           $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

           if(!$result){
                 die("Delete after check query failed!");
           } else {
                 echo "Delete after check query success!";
           }
      } elseif($_POST["deleteNo"]){
           echo "The course was not deleted!";
      }
?>
```

But the varibale `$selection` in the delete_confirmation.php file is always null even though i included the delete_items.php file (when i echo it, nothing is shown). Is there a way to pass the selection variable from delete_items.php to the delete_confirmation.php file?

Comment: You need to add `fruit` into the second form. Try using an hidden input, eg `echo '<input type="hidden" name="fruit" value="'.$selection.'"/>';`

Comment: @Phil thank you for your reply! I tried that and it did work. However, is there no way to do it with a yes and no button?

Comment: HTTP is stateless. You either pass the appropriate data with each request or persist it somewhere for later retrieval

Comment: @Phil Thank you so much for your explaination and for your answer  :)